# How to solve this error in ? flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, flutter-dependencies

Error: 'DatePickerTheme' is imported from both 'package:flutter/src/material/date_picker_theme.dart' and

'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart'.

I just want to solve this error in Flutter I stuck here for more than 3 hours. Help me to solve this with a genuine solution. I tried to find the package and removed it from there but it didn't solve.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the error says that Flutter SDK and that package use the same class DatePickerTheme,

If you want to use the same class from the package then use the import as below syntax:

```
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart' as fdp;
```

then in code use the fdp.(your desired method from that package)

That's it.
Happy Fluttering

Comment: can you give as exact code so I can paste it? or where should i put this is it in dateTimePickerTheme.dart?

Comment: @Ritesh, please provide your desired method/function from that class.

Answer (score 0):

The DatPickerTheme class is defined in material/date_picker_theme.dart and also defined in package of dateTimePicker

```
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/src/datetime_picker_theme.dart' as fdp;
```

use it like this:

```
fdp.DatePickerTheme
```

Comment: can you give as exact code so I can paste it? or where should i put this is it in dateTimePickerTheme.dart?